# EF Core Insert in many to many table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, ef-core-2.0

I scaffolded my User model with Razor Pages and on the create page I want to insert the user role on the junction table UserRoles.

this is my model

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        IsActivo = true;          
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Prompt = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Último Acesso")]
    public DateTime? DataSessao { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Activo")]
    public bool IsActivo { get; set; } 
    public Colaborador Colaborador { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the create model

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly HutIS.Models.HutISContext _context;

    public CreateModel(HutISContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        DepartamentosOptions = _context.Departamento.Select(d =>
              new SelectListItem
                  {
                       Value = d.Id.ToString(),
                       Text = d.Nome
                  }).ToList();


        RolesOptions = _context.Roles.Select(d =>
                  new SelectListItem
                      {
                         Value = d.Id.ToString(),
                         Text = d.Type
                       }).ToList();

        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DepartamentosOptions { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> RolesOptions { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.User.Add(User);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

on html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.UserRoles" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="User.UserRoles" asp-items="Model.RolesOptions" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="">Selecione um Departamento...</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="User.UserRoles" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I'm not exactly sure how can I do this, of course I get an exception here but how can I bind UserRoles if it's a collection in User ?

**EDIT**

I solved the exception problem, it was related with model properties. The problem now is that nothing is inserted on the UserRoles table, I'm not really sure what's the way to do this, since it's User has no navigation property to UserRoles unlike Departments.

[image]

as you can see the relations are correct

Comment: what is the problem/ exception you're facing ?

Comment: Updated post, the exception is solved but nothing is inserted

Comment: it seems that on frontend you're supposed to assign existing user roles to a user, where is the logic that might create new user roles?

Comment: It's in a different page, the model Role was scaffolded using razor CRUD. I know i could do this separatedly but i thought it was possible to assign a role to a user   while creating user. There are roles already created.

Comment: so, on this call roles will just be assigned to the user? have you looked at the inserted data in DB to verify if roles are assigned properly and if you're facing a problem in creating `UserRole` maybe you can share that code

Comment: that's the objective, insert user id and role id on the junction table. but nothing is being inserted. I think i have to model bind it as an array and insert first index but i'm not sure

Comment: the `SelectListItem` being populated, does this have `primary key` as value?

Comment: Correct, you can see on the code on the page Get method, also added image of the relations, they are correct

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that this is really a EF Core question not ASP.Net. You need to explicitly update the role relationship this won't happen for free. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `<select multiple="multiple" asp-for="User.RoleIds" asp-items="Model.RolesOptions" class="form-control form-control-sm">`, it will submit the RoleId value instead of Role Object, you need to define `public ICollection<int> UserRoleIds { get; set; }` to accept RoleIds.

Follow steps below:

1. Define a ViewModel with `UserRoleIds`

   ```
   public class UserVM
   {
       public UserVM()
       {
           IsActivo = true;
       }

       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Display(Prompt = "Username")]
       public string Username { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "Último Acesso")]
       public DateTime? DataSessao { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "Activo")]
       public bool IsActivo { get; set; }

       public ICollection<int> RoleIds { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Razor Model

   ```
   public class CreateModel : PageModel
   {
       private readonly TestRazorContext _context;

       public CreateModel(TestRazorContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }

       public IActionResult OnGet()
       {
           RolesOptions = _context.Role.Select(d =>
                   new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Value = d.Id.ToString(),
                       Text = d.Type
                   }).ToList();
           return Page();
       }

       [BindProperty]
       public UserVM User { get; set; }
       public List<SelectListItem> RolesOptions { get; set; }

       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
       {
           if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               return Page();
           }
           //create user
           var user = new User {
               Username = User.Username,
               //rest properties
           };
           _context.User.Add(user);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           //set user role
           var userRoles = new List<UserRoles>();
           foreach (var roleId in User.RoleIds)
           {
               userRoles.Add(new UserRoles
               {
                   UserId = user.Id,
                   RoleId = roleId
               });
           }
           _context.UserRole.AddRange(userRoles);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           return RedirectToPage("./Index");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Razor View

   ```
   <form method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label asp-for="User.Username" class="control-label"></label>
           <input asp-for="User.Username" />
       </div>    
       <div class="form-group">
           <label asp-for="User.RoleIds" class="control-label"></label>
           <select multiple="multiple" asp-for="User.RoleIds" asp-items="Model.RolesOptions" class="form-control form-control-sm">
               <option value="">Selecione um Departamento...</option>
           </select>
           <span asp-validation-for="User.RoleIds" class="text-danger"></span>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
   ```